# import var from file .js to template of module joomla, and modify with backoffice

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I did some research but could not find the solution... I'm implementing a script in a module joomla, everything seems to work regularly.
I should only change a function that should be regularly changed by varying a .JS 
In my case the change must take place from the back office module.
i have this var in .js file

```
var playListID = "PLSSPBo7OVSZs96Cr6nEnzQpRDGwih38ie"
```

in my  xml file to module have this field

```
<field name="playlist" type="text" label="playlist" />
```

What should I put in my default.php to do so by filling out the field take the variant inserted?

THANK YOU to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0):

OK! I have export the function and have insert htmlspecialchars

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var playListID = "<?= htmlspecialchars($params->get('playlist')); ?>"; 
    </script>
```

Is Perfect!